# python nltk loop printing header instead of the value

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, tokenize, stop-words

I have tokenized sentences in a csv file but when I'm trying to remove the stop words within the for loop it stops printing the words and it prints the column header for all sentences any idea where is the error in the last line ?

```
for review in tokenized_docs:
    new_review = []
    for token in review:
        new_token = x.sub(u'', token)
        if not new_token == u'':
            new_review.append(new_token)
    tokenized_docs_no_punctuation.append(new_review)
    words=pd.DataFrame(tokenized_docs_no_punctuation)
    #print(words)
    print([word for word in words if word not in stops])
```

the output shows like this

[image: on]

which should be the words instead of the column header numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `words` in your code is dataframe, `word` becomes column name (0, 1, 2,.. ) in for loop.

You can just change to list. For example,

```
# before
# words=pd.DataFrame(tokenized_docs_no_punctuation)

# after
words = tokenized_docs_no_punctuation[0]
```

worked for me.

Comment: I tried it now its correct but its printing the same sentence over and over again rather than jumping the next sentence

Comment: thank you , your answer helped me to figure out the problem, I changed the code to this way 
words = tokenized_docs_no_punctuation[0:]